# Hibernate java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError when launched in web application/servlet

Tags: java, hibernate, servlets

The code I am using with Hibernate runs fine when it is called by another class if I right-ckick the class and run as Java Application.

However, if I have a servlet call the same code when the servlet is running in a web application, there is an exception: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError.

What is the difference between running the same java code (including Hibernate) between calling it from a class directly (Run As Java Application) and calling it from a servlet in a web application?

How can I resolve this? Thanks!

Comment: could you explain more detail with your code

Comment: You should check the server's logs. Are you using tomcat? It's probably in /var/logs/tomcat7/catalina or something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally ExceptionInInitializerError error is thrown from static initializer block. And while using Hibernate, many prefer to create SessionFactory in static initializer block and if the creation fails because of any reason, ExceptionInInitializerError is thrown.

As you said, your code is running from your IDE independently but having issue while accessing it from container. So, It seems you are missing some Hibernate libraries in your war/ear file.

Please check all the dependencies are included in your web application archive.